# Invalid date format exception in SqliteDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sqlite

I run a select command in SQLite db has a column 'DATETIME'datatype.
When I fill DataTable with adapter "String was not recognized valid" exception occurs..
here code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string query = "select * from books"
cmd.CommandText = query;
SqliteDataAdapter da = new SqliteDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(dt);//exception throws on this line
```

My date format in db dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss, in server which program runs: MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
So I assume this causes the error. right ? how can I simply say to adapter fill dt with current date format, ignore ignore server.

Comment: Sqlite itself doesn't have any data type for `DateTime` they are all strings. You probably have some invalid date in your data and `SqliteDataAdapter` is trying to convert all the strings to date and failing. Try `SELECT * from BOOKS limit 1;` to make sure if you get a single record back in `DataTable`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the "datetimeformat" parameter to the connect string and should change the date format.  Change the datetimeformat parameter to current culture.

```
datetimeformat=CurrentCulture
```

The default date is ISO8601