# FormatException was not managed on DateTime

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

I'm in trouble with `DateTime`, in particular I'm going to read all record from a table in `sqlite`, now the column name is `StartDate` and is of `DateTime` format. This is how I'm trying to read the data:

```
dbCon.Open();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table_name;
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, dbCon);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
      Console.WriteLine(reader["StartDate"]);
      ..
```

but I get:

> FormatException was not managed

the date of the record is in this format
05/03/2016

Comment: Have you used the debugger? Is `reader["StartDate"]` really a `DateTime`? Where do you get the exception exactly? At `command.ExecuteReader()`, at `while (reader.Read())` or at `Console.WriteLine(reader["StartDate"])`?

Comment: I get the exception on the Console.WriteLine. Yes in the database table is a `DateTime`

Comment: Set a breakpoint at that line and try `((DateTime)reader["StartDate"]).ToString()` in the debugger. Do you get the same exception? In general a `DateTime` is not in a format since it has no format. It just has a value.

Comment: using the immediate window or just mouse over the variable and see what reader["StartDate"] says at that moment in time before it gets written

Comment: Interesting comment on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787426/invalid-date-format-exception-in-sqlitedataadapter

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, I get this error: string doesn't recognized as properly DateTime

Comment: @IlDrugo: that's strange. Either `reader["StartDate"]` is a `DateTime`, then you wouldn't get this compiler error, or it is a `String`, then you would get a different error(`System.InvalidCastException`). You normally get it when you try to parse a string to `DateTime`, but you haven't shown the code. However, it seems that it's not a `datetime` in the database but a `varchar`-column. You should change that asap.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The field in the db is `DateTime`, the strange thing is that the error happean on Console.WriteLine, I really don't understand why

Comment: @IlDrugo: same error with `reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("StartDate"))`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter unfortunately yes

Answer (score 1):

Okay after a lot of attempts, I found a solution, in particular `SQLite` doesn't seems to recognize the connection automatically, for fix this issue, we need to declare the source of connection like this:

```
source=<source to db file>;version=3;new=False;datetimeformat=CurrentCulture
```

and after it is possible read the date as following:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader["StartDate"]);
```

no errors returned, hope that this can help.